# functions which covers(good covers) manifolds

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be  a (not  necessarily compact)) smooth  manifold.

> 1.Is there a  smooth  map  $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$  and  an open covering $\mathbb{R}=\cup U_{\alpha}$ such that each $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?
>
> 2.Is there a smooth  map $f:M \to \mathbb{R}^{k}$, for  some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and  an open covering $\mathbb{R}^{k}=\cup U_{\alpha}$  such that $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$  is  a  good  cover for  $M$?

Comment: Does your definition of "manifold" include "second countable"?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes I mean the standard definition of  manifold.May be you are considering the long line?

Comment: Right, some people consider the long line to be a manifold and others do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1), the answer is almost always no; the combinatorial properties of open covers of $\mathbb{R}$ are far too restricted.  Suppose that $M$ is compact and connected and such an $f$ and $\{U_\alpha\}$ exist.  Let the image of $f$ be $[a,b]$.  Each $U_\alpha$ is a union of disjoint intervals; by connectedness, only one of those disjoint intervals can intersect $[a,b]$.  Restricting the codomain of $f$ to $[a,b]$, we may thus assume each $U_\alpha$ is a single interval.  Now take a minimal subcollection of $\{U_\alpha\}$ that still covers $[a,b]$: this will be a finite sequence of intervals $I_k=(x_k,y_k)$ going from left to right such that only consecutive intervals intersect.  That is, we have $$x_1\leq x_2\leq y_1\leq x_3\leq y_2\leq x_4\leq y_3 \leq\dots$$

Let $U$ be the union of the $f^{-1}(I_k)$ for $k$ odd and $V$ be the union of the $f^{-1}(I_k)$ for $k$ even.  Then both $U$ and $V$ are disjoint unions of copies of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and they cover $M$.  This implies that the [LS-category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusternik%E2%80%93Schnirelmann_category) of $M$ must be at most 1.  In particular, for instance, this implies that the cohomology of $M$ can have no nontrivial cup products.  If $M$ is not compact, a similar (but a little bit more difficult) argument can be made to reach the same conclusion.

Comment: what  about the following weaker version :In first question we consider the weaker statment:' $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ homeomorphic  to  an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$"?

Answer (score 3):

For 2., this might be nuking a mosquito, but here is an argument for existence of such $f$ assuming that $M$ is paracompact. WLOG, assume $M$ is connected (and hence second-countable). Use the Whitney embedding theorem to find an embedding $f: M \to \mathbb{R}^k$ as a closed submanifold of a Euclidean space; use this embedding to think of $M$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$. The Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$ restricts to a Riemannian metric on $M$. For each point $p \in M$, find a ball $B_{r(p)}(p)$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f^{-1}(B_{r(p)}(p)) = B_{r(p)}(p) \cap M$ is geodesically convex in $M$ (see [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wangzuoq/635W12/Notes/Lec%2022.pdf) for example). The $B_{r(p)}(p)$ plus the complement of $M$ then form an open cover $U_\alpha$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ for which the inverse images $f^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ form a good open cover.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I suspect this particular mosquito is genetically engineered to resist non-nuclear weaponry.  In other words, I think the result is no easier than the Whitney embedding theorem.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I suspect you're right. I confess that when I wrote those words, I was in the midst of deploying greater nuclear power by first putting a Riemannian structure on $M$, and then using the Nash embedding theorem to isometrically embed in Euclidean space. Then it occurred to me that the above would involve much less weaponry. :-)

Comment: @ToddTrimble  Thanks  for  your very interesting  answer. What  about the  following  possible definition:

Comment: For  a  manifold  $M$, we define the  minimum $k$  such that a  good  covering of $M$ can be  obtained  via pull back of  an open covering  of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ for  some  smooth  function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}^{k}$. Is this  invariant  some  how related to some thing as LS  category as in the answer of @Eric? As you said this  minimum is  less than $2n+1$. Thanks again for your interesting answer.